# Gzip Decompression Error

Tags: c#, gzip, gzipstream

I want to decompress a zip file.

The code that I used is so simple.

I could not understand why I' m getting this error;

**The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.**

```
        public static void Decompress(Stream fileToDecompress)
           {
           using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create("BinaryTest"))
           {
              using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(fileToDecompress, CompressionMode.Decompress))
              {
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);   **Error**
              }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if `fileToDecompress` is proper GZipStream? You can copy it locally to file and check if it is valid. The error show clean that data in the stream is not valid.

Comment: I got fileToDecompress = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("path"); Should I convert the stream to GZipStream?

Comment: So just copy this stream into file and check what it is inside. Instead of GZipStream use FileStream for testing. I'm 100% sure that this stream is not GZip

Answer (score 1):

gzip is not zip.  zip is not gzip.  You can use the [ZipFile class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) or [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to extract a zip file.